# Changes to Controller missing when run

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4.0 project (under VS2010) which has been working fine for a long time .   Today I added a line to a controller and placed a breakpoint on it.   When I started it in debug mode the breakpoint symbol hollowed out (hovering over it gives the "source code is different from the original version" message). I then discovered that I got the same problem if I put a breakpoint anywhere in the file. However,if I removed the new line and then compiled and ran again the breakpoints worked fine.  I also verified that the same problem exists in other controller files within this project but not in any of the class library projects that are included.

Doing a little experimentation I discovered that any change I make to any of the controllers in this project no longer appears to published to the dll. For example, I changed the text of a model variable and when I run it, it shows the previous text which would explain the hollow breakpoint symptom.

I verified that the project's dll and pdb files are being updated (I delete them and when I run in debug mode again, new files are created.   I have tried the usual solutions: removing and re-adding the project, deleting the obj files, switching the configuration between debug and release,deleting the  dev server instances,etc. I also tried deleting the whole temporary asp.net folder to no avail.

I did notice something that seems odd.  In the bin folder there are three copies of the project's dll, one under debug, one under release and one under the root of the bin folder. The dlls in the debug and release folder show today's date but the one in the root of the bin shows yesterday. Curiously, all of the other dll's in the root of the bin folder which are compiled in the solution show today.

Comment: Out of curiosity I deleted the out of date dll's in the root of the bin folder and when I built again it did generate new ones but now I get an error "Could not load type x.MvcApplication".   Note that the build output folder set for  this project is Bin\Release\

Comment: Sometimes you just need to open the .csproj file directly and compare the non-working project to a working one. Could also be in the .sln file.